# Angular2 - Get Name When Using Dynamic Component Loader Wrapper To Display List of Components

Tags: angular, factory, ng2-dragula

I'm using a Dynamic Component Loader to display a list of components with a *ngFor:

```
<div [dragula]='"bag-one"' [dragulaModel]='types'>
  <div *ngFor="let component of types; let i = index">
    <dcl-wrapper [type]="component" [index]="i"></dcl-wrapper>
  </div>
</div>
```

With types being an array: `types = [ TestAComponent, TestBComponent, TestCComponent];`

Within the dcl-wrapper component I have been able to access the index of the components but I cannot figure out how to output the name of the components. I used [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UGzoPTCHlXKWrn4p8gd1?p=preview) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) as an example if you want all the code, but for the relevant code for this part looks like this:

```
export class DclWrapperComponent {

  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
  @Input() type;
  @Input()
    set name(component: string){
      this.name = component;
    }
  @Input() 
    set index(i: number){
      this._index = i;
      console.log("Item index changed: ", this._index, this.name);
    }
```

...

and I get:

```
Item index changed:  0 undefined
Item index changed:  1 undefined
Item index changed:  2 undefined
```

Could anyone explain where I'm going wrong? Or if you know of a better way to get the name/id/whatever of the component that is being moved I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out but would appreciate any and all feedback if I'm following best practices.

First I added a componentName Input to the components that are going to be displayed by the D.C.L. like this:

```
@Input() componentName = 'whateverComponentNameHere';
```

And then added to my factory an additional property to each instance like this:

```
let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.type);
this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)

console.log(this.cmpRef.instance.componentName + ": " + this._index);
^^^Can access like this.

this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```